# In RoR, is there an easy way to prevent the view from outputting <p> tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby and Rails and I have a simple controller that shows an item from the database in a default view. When it is displaying in HTML it is outputting `<p>` tags along with the text content. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? I suppose if there isn't, is there at least a way to set the default css class for the same output in a statement such as this:

```
<% @Items.each do |i| %>

    <%= i.itemname %>
    <div class="menu_body">
           <a href="#">Link-1</a>
           </div>
<% end %>
```

So the problem is with the `<%= i.itemname %>` part. Is there a way to stop it from wrapping it in its own `<p>` tags? Or set the css class for the output?

Thanks!

Comment: Rails does not output the p tags by itself. You're probably using `simple_format`.

Comment: FYI - It is very unusual to start the name of an instance variable with a capital letter. It's legal, but not typical Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enclose it with the HTML tag of your choice. Also if required you can escape bad code by using `<%=h i.itemname %>` Example:

```
<% @Items.each do |i| %>

    <div><%=h i.itemname %></div>
    <div class="menu_body">
           <a href="#">Link-1</a>
           </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit: Ryan Bigg is right. Rails doesn't output a `<p>` tag. Sorry for the wrong info.

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't even realize RoR added paragraph elements if you didn't wrap your stuff properly.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Good lord, it somehow stored it in the database with P tags in the first place. Sorry, but thanks for the info, I learned something anyway!

Comment: Aha! I figured out your prob at last! The `<p>` tags are being added simply because you weren't escaping your output. Thats why you use `<%=h i.itemname %>` most of the times and not just `<%= i.itemname %>` Say even if you added a div tag around `<%= i.itemname %>` it will still output a `<p>` tag if you have content with `<p>` tag stored in the database! Hope that clarifies your issue with rails outputting `<p>` tags! Cheers! :) (Figured out when you said `it somehow stored it in the database with P tags in the first place`)

Answer (score -1):

You canchange the public/stylesheets/scaffold.css if you want.

Or if you want to change it for a single page say items/index.html.erb

```
<style> 
p{
/* your style here *?

}

</style>
```

Comment: He said it's outputting p tags when he doesn't want it to; he didn't mention stylesheets at all.